# Restrict for loop in Python for specific iterations

Tags: python

for this list ,

```
l=[i for i in range(1,100)]
```

How can i restrict to print only 1st 20 elements.

What i am trying to do is ,

```
>>> counter=0
>>> for index , i in enumerate(l):
...    if counter==20:
...        break
...    print index , i
...    counter+=1
...
```

Is there is another way to do this without using `counter` variable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a sliced list, like this

```
l=[i for i in range(1,100)]
for index, i in enumerate(l[:20]):
    print index, i
```

Or you can use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), to avoid generating entire list and instead iterate over `xrange` as long as you want, like this

```
from itertools import islice
for index, i in enumerate(islice(xrange(1, 100), 20)):
    print index, i
```

Answer (score 1):

Nishant N.'s answer is the probably the best. But your code would also have worked had you changed your `if` statement to read

```
if i == 20:
```

Just in case you wondered why it wasn't working (also you would have needed to set `counter` to 0 before the code you posted, but I accept that may just have been omitted.